# ASP MVC WebSecurity not in webserver

Tags: asp.net-mvc, security, simplemembership

Just wondering, is it possible to use the functionality of WebMatrix.WebSecurty, and WebMatrix.Roles outside of the asp mvc application? For example, using this on a console based application, or on a business logic component to manage all the users and roles creation? I have tried making a simple console application but i keep getting an exception when trying to initialize WebSecurity.
The reason of all this, is that i need to have all the logic on a different component from the webserver, being the webserver only responsable of consuming such services. But implementing all the user management myself when having WebSecurity already would be a waste.

```
WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("DefaultConnection", "UserProfile", "UserId", "UserName", autoCreateTables: true);
```